# Параметр в названии скрипта index.html при build (angular)

Tags: javascript, html, angular, webpack

Сгенерированная папка dist содержит в себе index.html А он содержит что-то типа:

```
<script src="runtime-es2015.f56e2e5f2e4e679915fd.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="runtime-es5.f56e2e5f2e4e679915fd.js" nomodule defer></script>
<script src="polyfills-es5.d3a62c7946c75902bf81.js" nomodule defer></script>
```

Хотелось бы видеть эти скрипты в виде - script_name.js?{{мой_параметр}}.
Например, runtime-es2015.f56e2e5f2e4e679915fd.js?v=123

Пробовала сделать через webpack, но не особо разбираюсь в нем, поэтому результатов пока нет.
Может вообще для поиска решения в другую сторону нужно посмотреть?

Вот мои наброски в конфиге вебпака:

```
 optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: false
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].[ext]?v=[contenthash]'
  },
```

Вместо contenthash другое буду подставлять, пока не знаю как именно, но буду :)

Потом пробовала еще лоадеры использовать, но тоже ничего

```
 module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            query: {
              name: '[name].[ext]?[ext]'
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Правки:

```
module.exports = (config) => {
  config.output.filename = '[name].js?v=4';
  return config;
};
```

Comment: нужно извлекать и  править конфиги вебпака. А зачем вам это нужно, если не секрет?

Comment: в параметре предполагается указывать  commit_ref_name, для наглядности

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko добавила свои настройки в описание

Comment: @Анастасия это непростая задача, кажется лучше делегировать это другому человеку на работе :) А вообще, что ты используешь для того, чтобы оверайдить конфиг вебпака?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko  в angular json в качестве билдера @angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser использую и там файл с webpack.config.js указала

Comment: @Анастасия это я спросил, не Степан  версия Angular?

Comment: @overthesanity извините, проглядела) пока что 8, но на 9 уже переведено приложение - зарелизим буквально через 2 дня

Comment: ок. Для того, чтобы изменить названия файлов - нужно изменять свойство `filename` по ссылке. `module.exports` в `webpack.config` может возвращать фабрику, которая 1м параметром принимает конфиг - `module.exports = config => config;`. Нужно внутри функции изменить свойство `filename`, по дефолту вебпак использует `[name]-es2015.[chunkhash:20].js`, тебе нужно поменять на `config.output.filename = '[name]-es2015.[chunkhash:20].js?v=COMMIT_HASH'`

Comment: @overthesanity добавила в описание, что-то типа такого?

Comment: @Анастасия ну ты проверила? работает? :)

Comment: @overthesanity поэтому и спрашиваю, вообще скрипты не добавились)

Comment: да, он не добавит скрипты в `index.html` [из-за этого фильтра](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/angular_devkit/build_angular/src/angular-cli-files/utilities/index-file/augment-index-html.ts#L82). CLI использует `path.extname('qwe.js?v=qweqwe')`, который возвращает `.js?v=qweqwe`. Тогда не добавляй хеш в виде квери в конце, а добавляй в середине между названием и экстеншеном - `[name].${COMMIT_HASH}.js`, это будет работать

Comment: Вся суть проблемы как раз в том, чтобы добавить именно в query

Comment: ну я тебе объяснил и даже показал, почему это невозможно) всегда можно найти компромисс в решении любой задачи в виду определенных ограничений

Comment: а какая вообще краеугольная цель всего этого? это требует бизнес или просто кому-то взбрело в голову "а давайте...."?

Comment: @overthesanity последнее..

Answer (score 0):

Правки внутри конфига вебпака не дадут результата, если каждый файл должен быть именован по разному.

Чтобы это сделать, большинство загрузчиков и плагинов позволяют вместо строки передавать функцию. Попробуйте посмотреть документацию.